# sharepoint public form

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2007, anonymous

I have a MOSS 2007 running a site that has a public facing form that any anonymous user can fill and save. But I require that only blank forms are visible to anonymous user and that the forms filled up by other users are not visible/accesible to anonymous users.

For that I have a form library(form1) that is authentication-protected, and another form library(form2) that is available to public. My arrangement is that anonymous user fills out form from form2, and saves it in form1. But while implementing it this way, I get "Error while submitting the form" error.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create simple workflow that move new document from public document library to protected one. Or you can email enable document library to get filled form as attachment to protected document library. 

 
Here free workshop on with videos, detailed descriptions of the development environment etc. on how to build SharePoint Workflows. http://rshelton.com/archive/2007/10/05/free-workshop-sharepoint-document-workflow-for-developers---part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do that is resorting to event handler! (Assume you know basic code) 
Hope this blog helps you a bit, otherwise google it. http://blogs.msdn.com/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you trust your authenticated users? If so, the easiest way would be to give them manage list permission and change the View/Edit access settings for the list.

You find them under "List settings -> Advanced Settings -> Item-level Permissions".

That way you can have everything in the same list.